# Bootstrap 5 - Make div with flex-grow-1 class scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make the indicated div below scrollable, but it always seems to extend the document size beyond screen space instead of creating a scrollbar. One solution is to set a fixed pixel height for the div, but I want to avoid this to ensure scalability between devices. Any ideas?

```html
<div class="row no-gutters w-100 flex-grow-1">
  <div class="col-8">
    <div id="playarea" class="container-fluid border-top border-end h-100 px-0">
      <!-- Cards go here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="container-fluid border rounded-top w-100 h-100 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="container my-3 d-flex mb-0">
        <h5 class="flex-grow-1">Side Content</h5>
      </div>
  
      <hr class="border mt-2 mb-3">
  
      <div class="container mb-3 d-flex">
        <!-- Non-scrollable search area -->
      </div>
  
      <div class="container flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
        <!-- Scrollable content goes here -->
      </div>
  
      <div class="card mt-2 bg-light mb-3" id="info-panel">
        <div class="card-body">
          <!-- Non-scrollable info box -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What's the max-height before that inner container should overflow scroll? The viewport height? The height  of `col-8`? The height of the container `row` is a child of? I ask because it makes quite the difference on how to achieve it.

Comment: @Cooleronie sorry for my poor wording, it should overflow when it exceeds the remaining height of its parent container - essentially its flexbox should grow to fit the remaining space of the parent container after added siblings, but once this is exceeded, create a scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing because your `.row` has `.flex-grow-1` which one would only add if you want `.row` to grow in available height of its parent, not in width. This would mean `.row` should always have a height and my solution can be simplified. So let me know if that's the case, because my answer assumes `.row` has no height.

My solution that requires no *fixed* height uses a container inside `col-4` with absolute positioning:

```
  #overflow-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: inherit;
  }
```

This container will take up all available space inside `col-4` and will grow or shrink with it. Now the element with `overflow: scroll` will work as you want.

The only drawback here is that if `col-8` (or `row`) has no content - and thus no height - the `#overflow-container` will also have no height and any content inside the `.overflow-auto` element will not be visible. **So if `col-8` can be empty, a `min-height` on `col-4`s parent is needed.**

The line `padding: inherit` is there to give the column its padding back; Bootstrap uses the selector `row > *`  to give columns their padding.

I removed all unnecessary classes for this snippet to work for simplicity, but I added the `sm` breakpoint on the columns so they stack on mobile screen sizes. If you don't want this, you can simply remove the `-sm` part on the columns and the `@media` in the CSS. It's only there to show how it can be done.

```css
.col-sm-8 {
  background: lightyellow;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  background: lightgreen;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  #overflow-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <p>This column should have enough content...</p>
      <br><br><br><br><br>
      <p>...So `Overflowing content` will have a height.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 position-relative">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="overflow-container">
        <div class="">
          <h5>Aside Content</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <p>Some content here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overflow-auto">
          <p>Overflowing content.</p>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <p>Unless col-8 is long enough for me to fit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <p>Some content here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```